# I'm trying to display a big text that I'm getting from my Apex Controller on my Aura component, Please Help

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I'm trying to display text from my apex controller but I'm not getting anything, can someone point out where I'm going wrong and how to fix it.

```
<aura:component controller="DisplayLegalTextHandler" implements="force:appHostable,lightning:isUrlAddressable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasrecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="URL" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<p>Legal Text </p>

    <div>
        <lightning:formattedText name="legText" value="{!this}" />
        
    </div>

</aura:component>

Here is my Js class

({
            doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
            var LegalText = component.find("c.getLegalText").get("v.value");
            component.set("v.legText",LegalText);
        }

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm the below:

1. Does your apex have @AuraEnabled annotated for the method and for the variables you will be passing to Aura component?
2. Also i noticed your doInit method does not perform EnqueueAction to backend?

Let me know.

---

**Updated 23-Jun**

Below was Aura code and Apex to assist you.

**Component**

```
<aura:component controller="DisplayLegalTextHandler" 
                implements="force:appHostable,lightning:isUrlAddressable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasrecordId">
    
    <aura:attribute name="URL" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <p>Legal Text </p>
    
    <div>
        <lightning:formattedText aura:id="legText" name="legText" />
    </div>
    
</aura:component>
```

**Controller.js**

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getLegalText");
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            component.find("legText").set("v.value", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**Apex**

```
public class DisplayLegalTextHandler {
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getLegalText() {
        return 'Some Legal Text returned to Aura';
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Yes I currently added an enqueue action in my js controller and I already added @AuraEnabled to the method that I'm calling in the component. But it is still showing blank screen.

Comment: Can you check m post with latest update and try out? Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Hi Suni Kumar, thanks for your help. I made the mistake of putting different names in Apex and Js controller, fixed it and now it is working :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an aura attribute "legText" and assign this attribute as value for lightning:formattedText.
When you are doing "component.set("v.legText",LegalText)", you are setting value in an attribute "legText", which you have not defined.

Following is how your markup would look like:

```
<aura:component controller="DisplayLegalTextHandler" implements="force:appHostable,lightning:isUrlAddressable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasrecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="URL" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="legText" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<p>Legal Text </p>

    <div>
        <lightning:formattedText name="legText" value="{!v.legText}" />
        
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

Comment: No, it is not working, I'm not sure where the problem is, I'm just getting a blank screen with nothing in it. It opens to a new tab and the tab heading just shows loading. I created a button so this component runs in a new tab.